# Full Outer Join Not including all records from both sides

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a calendar table with dates from 2000 through 2029. I have done a full outer join with my data table on date=tdate. My goal is to count trips occurring by date and to show a zero if there are no trips. However, all dates are not showing up. If there is no trip date in the data table, the date from the Calendar table does not show up at all. I've never seen this happen before. I've tried changing it to a left outer join which didn't work either. Actual query below.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT c.DATE,
        COALESCE(COUNT(t.TripID), 0) AS tripCount
    FROM dbo.Calendar c
    FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.TripsMade t ON c.DATE = CONVERT(DATE, t.tripdate, 126)
    WHERE (c.DATE BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2019-09-30' )
      AND (t.compid = 270 OR t.compid IS NULL)
    GROUP BY c.DATE
    ORDER BY c.DATE
```

If I select all dates from the Calendar Table, they are all there. There are dates missing from the Data Table, and always will have some missing. I need all dates to show up on this report and show a zero if there are no associated records on the Data Table side.

What am I missing here?

Goal
DATE            TOTAL_TRIPS
2019-09-01             3
2019-09-02             5
2019-09-03             0  <== This row is currently missing completely
2019-09-04             4
2019-09-05             0  <== This row is currently missing completely
2019-09-06             9

Comment: Your `WHERE` turns it into an implicit `INNER JOIN`, due to not handling `NULL` values for `c.Date`. `t.compid=270` should be in the `ON` as well, and then you can remove `t.compid IS NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause ends up filtering non-matches out from both tables, turning them almost into `INNER JOIN`s (it is a little complicated with the condition on `t`.

I don't think you need a `FULL JOIN`.  I suspect you want a `LEFT JOIN` with filtering (for the second table) in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.Date, COUNT(t.TripID) AS tripCount
FROM dbo.Calendar c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.TripsMade t
     ON c.date = CONVERT(DATE, t.tripdate, 126) AND
        t.compid = 270
WHERE c.Date BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2019-09-30'
GROUP BY c.Date
ORDER BY c.Date;
```

If `compid` can actually take on `NULL` values and you want them, then use `(t.compid = 270 OR t.compid IS NULL)`.  I suspect, though, that is not what you want.  The `NULL` just represents a non-match on the `JOIN`.

Notes:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost *never* used with `GROUP BY`, and it is not needed in this case.
- `COUNT()` does not return `NULL`, so there is no need for `COALESCE()`.
- Filtering on the *first* table does belong in the `WHERE` clause.